# GPU Temperature Applet interfering with GPU function

Tags: linux-mint, gpu, temperature

I have a dual booting PC (**Mint 18.3** with Windows 10). My graphics card is a **NVIDIA GeForce GT710**.

*While using Linux*, I noticed that the GPU Temperature reached **57-60°C** with simple Internet browsing (it used to be 45-50 even while multitasking), the **fan roared** and the **picture froze** momentarily (with sound working normally) every few minutes while watching videos online.

All the above stopped when I uninstalled the **GPU Temperature Applet** and I have had no issues ever since the un-installation. I now use the Psensor and everything is ok.

Has anyone else had similar issues with the certain applet?